# Excel formula to show smallest divisor of a number

Tags: microsoft-excel

So far I was able to print number if it is prime or "" otherwise:

```
=IF(A2=2,"Prime",IF(AND(MOD(A2,ROW(INDIRECT("2:"&ROUNDUP(SQRT(A2),0))))<>0),A2,""))
```

Is it possible to change formula to print the smallest divisor of a number if it is compound?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You test of `AND(MOD(A2,ROW(INDIRECT("2:"&ROUNDUP(SQRT(A2),0))))<>0)` is returning any number that does not evenly divide into another number.  So we want the opposite:

```
MOD(A3,ROW(INDIRECT("2:"&ROUNDUP(SQRT(A3),0))))=0
```

But we want the minimum number where this is true:

```
MIN(IF(MOD(A3,ROW(INDIRECT("2:"&ROUNDUP(SQRT(A3),0))))=0,ROW(INDIRECT("2:"&ROUNDUP(SQRT(A3),0)))))
```

Put that in place of the false of the inner IF.

It will iterate from 2 to the sqrt of the number and return the minimum value that evenly divides into that number.

so:

```
=IF(A2=2,"Prime",IF(AND(MOD(A2,ROW(INDIRECT("2:"&ROUNDUP(SQRT(A2),0))))<>0),A2,MIN(IF(MOD(A2,ROW(INDIRECT("2:" & A2)))=0,ROW(INDIRECT("2:" & A2))))))
```

This is an array formula and must be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting edit mode.

[image]